# i have "fatal error" in the project

Tags: java, android, eclipse-adt

I add external jar, set the build path

And now on the project icon i have  ! (in red)

When i try to run i get this message on the console:

```
Invalid layout of java.lang.String at value

A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:124), pid=5512, tid=1388
fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class

JRE version:  (8.0_11-b12) (build )
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.11-b03 mixed mode windows-x86 )
Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

An error report file with more information is saved as:
C:\Users\David\workspace\feed4jRss\hs_err_pid5512.log

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jar file was compile using a new version, and the jar file that your are using is the old version. issues of compability:  try to change the jar file, and you should be good.